# ModSecurity Configuration > Installation Failed. None

Tags: security, server, vps, cyber-panel

Moved from Hostinger Shared to Hostinger Cyberpanel VPS.
OS: Centos 7
CyberPanel: v2.3.2

**Problem:**
Server > Security > ModSecurity Conf > Install Now > "**Installation failed. None**"
**Text***

```
Loaded plugins: copr, fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.centos.iad1.serverforge.org
 * epel: mirror.coastal.edu
 * extras: mirror.dal.nexril.net
 * updates: mirror.centos.iad1.serverforge.org
10 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ols-modsecurity.x86_64 0:1.7.16-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package              Arch        Version           Repository             Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 ols-modsecurity      x86_64      1.7.16-2.el7      litespeed-update       16 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 16 M
Installed size: 71 M
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Can not be installed.[404]
```

**End Text**

**What I've done:**
Reinstalled the OS: Centos 7
Contacted the following support:
Hostinger
Cyberpanel both paid support and the community.

**Results:**
Waiting for replies, no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved! Hostinger support gave me the right guidance to solve this problem.

Note: The following is what I did. I'm using a Mac running macOS Catalina. Window folks will need Pudy. Also, this worked for my specific situation described in my first post.

1. On Mac, make sure the Terminal can run "zsh shell". I rarely use the Terminal, when I opened it there was some command that I needed to run to get the terminal to run 'zsh'. Like I said, Newbie here.

(Article reference: https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/56921-moving-from-bash-to-zsh-terminal-changes-in-macos-catalina/)

2. Terminal now set to run Zsh shell, I went to my Cyberpanal > Overview > VPS access > Terminal > copied the text paste into Terminal.
3. Pasted my root password.
4. I went to the following article: https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/3766/How-to-install-mod-security-on-Centos-7-x-with-apache-.html
5. Under heading: "Please refer to the following steps to install mod security on ContOS  7.X:

> Only did steps 1 and 2. Step 3 is optional if you're curious.

6. Finally, I went back to CyberPanel > Security > ModSecurity Conf > Install Now

**Result: Success!**